# Generalizing Steinitz's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

By "Steinitz's theorem" I mean his theorem that a graph is the graph of a three-dimensional convex polyhedron iff it is of genus 0 and has a vertex connectivity of at least three. Can a similar characterization be made for genus 1, or beyond?

Comment: The paper "The toroidal analogue to Eberhard's theorem" by Peter Gritzmann *may* be relevant, but I cannot access it. [Cambridge Link](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=6987680).

Comment: What kind of generalization are you looking for? You are not going to find a convex embedding...

Comment: Obviously a replacement for convexity would be required. The point is to define a geometrically defined object, which would of course have a donut hole, whose graph is precisely genus 1 with vertex connectivity at least 3 (ie, 3-connected.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no direct generalization is known. One related result (which seems to have come out of an attempt to generalize Steinitz) is [this paper by D. Eppstein and E. Mumford.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0537) However, since Steinitz' theorem is a simple consequence of the circle packing theorem, one can reasonably argue that the circle packing and its more general versions are the correct generalization -- unfortunately (or fortunately, for some of us) they move you into hyperbolic space. For recent work on this subject see the work of [Francois Fillastre.](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all%3a+Fillastre/0/1/0/all/0/1)